# Stomp ActiveMQ questions

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp, custom-protocol

I am new to Stomp ActiveMQ. I want to create a login from an android client and I don't know how to use ActiveMq. I\ve installed active mq, configured stomp and run the stompexample.
1. I have an error when running activemq from command line if I add in in the activemq.xml the following line:

```
 <transportConnector name="stomp+nio" uri="stomp+nio://localhost:61612"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp+ssl" uri="stomp+ssl://localhost:61612"/>
```

1. Can someone please explain what is with tx1 and tx2? Is there a way to send on the queue a message to a specific client? how?

   connection.connect("system", "manager");

   ```
       connection.begin("tx1");
       connection.send("/queue/test", "message1");
       connection.send("/queue/test", "message2");
       connection.commit("tx1");

       connection.subscribe("/queue/test", Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT);

       connection.begin("tx2");

       StompFrame message = connection.receive();
       System.out.println(message.getBody());
       connection.ack(message, "tx2");

       message = connection.receive();
       System.out.println(message.getBody());
       connection.ack(message, "tx2");

       connection.commit("tx2");

       connection.disconnect();
   ```
2. Can someone please tell me how to create an application that sends on a queue a text containing username, password and receives an answer if the register was successful?

Comment: hi did you manage to figure out what the txt1 and txt2 for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the transport connectors with different port numbers, they can't both share port 61612.  Your configure is create a Stomp NIO connector and a different Stomp SSL Connector.

You can't send messages to a distinct client, you just place them on a Queue and if there is a client subscribed it will get the message, that's the nature of Queue based messaging.  The TX1 TX2 stuff is sending the messages within a transaction.

Recommend you take some time to read up of JMS Messaging, the Stomp spec and some other messaging based tutorials.

Comment: could you post some tutorials with stomp? are there any examples with android client? i did a search but i didn't find anything on andrid - android example.

Comment: also is there a way to combine stomp with jms? if for example from android (stomp) i post on a queue eg:test a message i would like on the "server side" (jms receiver) to get the message. is it possible?

Comment: It's pretty much possible to mix STOMP and JMS. I think you just need to go over some more tutorials about STOMP & JMS to understand these better.